# Qt: How to make one thread wait for a temporary roadblock, and temporarily increase another thread's priority to remove the roadbock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have two threads:

- GUI, which does the typical GUI stuff and manages a bunch of flags that affect the Processing thread
- Processing, which handles realtime data on a 30Hz period forever

There are lots of examples of how to have one thread wait for another to *finish*, but none for how to make a temporary roadbock *without* killing the thread.

There's a function in my GUI thread that contains this:

```
Scene* scene = getSceneToFadeFrom();
scene->setSelected(false);
///TODO: wait until (!scene->processing)
fadeFrom = scene->dmx;
```

and one in my Processing thread that contains this while looping through a QList:

```
if(scene->getSelected())
{
    scene->processing = true;
    scene->run();              //updates scene->dmx
    scene->processing = false;
}
```

If this were an embedded project on bare metal, I could use the global interrupt enable flag in place of `scene->processing` (invert the logic) and be done, which dedicates the entire CPU to that task at the expense of all others.

But because this is a desktop project with an operating system to play nice with, how can I achieve the same effect within this project?  Basically, pause the GUI thread at that point until `scene->processing == false` (which it might be already) and guarantee that the Processing thread is actually running while the GUI thread waits for it.

Answer (score 0):

And here's what I came up with.  It was actually an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  I'm surprised that I didn't think of this right away because I had already done something similar for deleting a `Scene`:

GUI thread:

```
//(sceneToReplace != 0) means there's something for Processing to do
sceneToReplace = getSceneToFadeFrom();
if(sceneToReplace)
{
    sceneToReplace->setSelected(false);
}
```

Processing thread, same class:

```
if(sceneToReplace)
{
    fadeFrom = sceneToReplace->dmx;
    sceneToReplace = 0;
}
```

and I don't even need the `processing` flag anymore!

`fadeFrom` gets set a little later than in the original veresion, but it's not actually needed until then anyway.